# How to connect 2 different list in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file with a column containing parents name, another column containing the student name and the last one having their marks. I use the following code to extract the names of both parents and students

```
parents<-unique(c(mydata[, 2]))
students<-unique(c(mydata[,3]))
```

I want to know how to connect these 2 data such that whenever I enter a student or parent name I should be able to get the info about marks.

Comment: `cbind(parents, students)`? Your title and question don't match + what you're asking for is unclear.

Comment: if you have the data loaaded into an object, it would be better to add a small sample of the data.